# Only one dot "." regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I need to be able to set an input in order to put only numbers and one dot, like `111.111` and not `111..110....11` or `11.11.11.11`.

This is because I am doing a calculation, and if the user enters more than one dot in the same input, then the calculation stops, I have this in a directive

```
.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
        var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
        if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return transformedInput;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

so what should I do here

```
var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
```

?

**UPDATE**

here is the code where I am trying to use it: https://jsfiddle.net/dado1ynj/4/

Comment: `/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/` - i.e. Two zero to (any) length of numbers separated by a single dot.

Comment: You could match vs. `/^\d+\.\d+$/`, right?

Comment: I'm a complete idiot for forgetting the start `^` and end `$` anchors, @tadman's got it

Comment: @tadman try do it with my code https://jsfiddle.net/dado1ynj/4/ I am trying to implement it but I am not getting it. I am still able to enter more than one dot

Comment: @AdamKewley see the comment I post to Tadman with this link https://jsfiddle.net/dado1ynj/4/

Comment: `var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.]+|(?=.*\..*)\./g, '')`

Comment: @stribizhev it is ok but I am unable to enter dots now

Comment: You're inverting the logic here. I think you should only *accept* certain values, not try and clean up the input arbitrarily.

Comment: Yeah, when trying this code out, I also realized that you *have* to enter an invalid input before you can even get a valid one (e.g. typing `1` is *technically* invalid even if you intend to write `1.1` later). Obvious when I thought about it.

Comment: You could keep it simple and after transforming, just do `if (transformedInput.split('.').length<=2) { ... do calc ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but it checks the input as the user types and only allows a number with a single decimal.

```
 link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        scope.currentValue = '';
        element.bind('keyup',function(e) {
            if( e.which!=8 && e.which!=0 && e.which!=46 && e.which != 190 && (e.which<48 || e.which>57)) {
                element.val(scope.currentValue);
            }
            if(e.which != 8 && e.which != 0) {
                var valToCheck = element.val();

                var r = /^(\d*)\.{0,1}(\d*)$/
                if (!r.test(valToCheck)) {
                    element.val(scope.currentValue);
                } else {
                    scope.currentValue = element.val();
                }

            }


        });
```

The problem with this is that you see the user type in a letter, for example, and then you see it disappear. This works much better using "keypress" rather than "keyup" however then you have to take into account the user clicking the mouse somewhere in the middle of the currently inputted value and then typing so it gets tricky.

Answer (score 5):

Either use a lookahead:

```
^(?!.*\..*\.)(\d+\.\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kF0hJ5/1)

Or anchors:

```
^(\d+\.\d+)$
```

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/kF0hJ5/2)

Comment: try to adapt it to my code, https://jsfiddle.net/dado1ynj/4/ still allows me to set more than one dot

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer did you even try this answer out? Your comment comes across as extremely lazy...

Comment: yes, I am trying, and still getting the same. Sorry

Comment: Both the first and 2nd example works for me, i suspect your implementation of the regex is to blame.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends about what is the format that you will accept. 
Using /^(\d)*(.)?(\d)*$/ will help you to ensure that there is only one point in the number, but also accepts numbers without decimal point or just the decimal point. Also you can use isNaN() to make sure it is a number.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I just saw that the editor erased the exact string, it should be:  /^(\d)*(.)?(\d)*$/

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest just testing for more than 1 dot. Example

```
(string.test(/\d\.\.?(\.+)/gm)) ? //do true : // do false;
```

`test` checks if it exists in string and then returns true or false.

the regex checks for a digit then two dots or two dots +. It checks globally and multiple lines.

Then if you're insistant on using regex to check for three groups of three digits separated by one dot you can use the regex expression

```
/(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3})\b/gm
```

Example here: http://regexr.com/3auj5

Comment: try to adapt it to my code, https://jsfiddle.net/dado1ynj/4/ still allows me to set more than one dot

Comment: I don't want to give the user the option to do this 1.1.2.1.22, only 111.111

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer All this answer is designed to do is test for more than one dot. You want each number to have 3 digits?

Comment: @zfrisch your regex only matches `11..11`, not `11.11.11`

Comment: @KevinB my regex tests if there's more than one dot in a row. I thought that's all that was being requested. I'm currently working on it to update.

Comment: nope, it doesn't matter the number of digits. I am trying to adapt it to my code, but I can't

Comment: yes, the user should not put 11..11, I need only one dot after a number, not 2 or 3 dots

Comment: I added the regex for three groups of three separated by a dot. @NietzscheProgrammer